# Is there a Visual Studio or Resharper plugin that shows broken HtmlHelpers?

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-extensions

I am refactoring a several large controllers into individual controllers for readablity and for the Single Responsability Principle.

Is there a plugin / extension that shows me which views have broken Html helpers in them?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. You might also try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/